# Execute the command "ls -d */" with subprocess.Popen vs. os.popen

Tags: python, linux

On Linux OS, the python code below provides the directories inside the current directory.

```
dirs = os.popen('ls -d */').read().split(os.linesep)
print dirs
```

Because `os.popen` is deprecated, I'm migrating this call to `subprocess.Popen`

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-d', '*/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
outp = proc.stdout.read()
print outp
```

However for some reason this doesn't work, I get the following error

```
ls: cannot access */: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Star-expansion is done by the shell, which `Popen` doesn't use unless you add `shell=True`.

Comment: Side-note: `.split(os.linesep)` is better expressed as `.splitlines()` (which will avoid keeping a trailing empty string when the file ends in a newline). Or in the case of reading from a file-like object, you can do `lines = map(str.rstrip, filelikeobj)` to strip as you read, instead of slurping, then splitting.

Comment: BTW, editing answers into questions is frowned on here, and explicit advice from meta is to edit them out when they're offered (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question).

Comment: BTW, the reason `['ls', '-d', '*/']` with `shell=True` showed you everything is that in that mode, the `-d` and the `*/` are passed as arguments *to the shell*, not to `ls`; you would need to run `['ls "$@"', '-d', '*/']` to pass them through... though that would put you back to your original bug, as it would be passing `*/` as a literal rather than expanding it as a glob.

Comment: @Charles, I appreciate all help and always try to help others, and I really don't care about the grumpy people on SO.

Comment: The point of discussing policy on meta is deciding, as a community, how best to help others. Editing answers into questions is genuinely harmful towards that goal, as it creates an effective class of "special" answers no longer subject to the same upvoting/downvoting/acceptance/display rules as everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*/` only works if globbing is being performed; in `os.popen`, the whole string is being evaluated by a shell which is wrapping the actual `ls` process, and the shell is performing the expansion. When you use the `list` based `Popen`, it's passing the literal string `*/` to `ls`, and `ls` doesn't expand globs on its own.

You could pass a `str` and `shell=True` to `Popen`, but that's just reopening the performance, security and stability holes that `os.popen` has. Easier is to avoid subprocesses at all, just use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) or one of `os.listdir`/[`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir)/`os.walk` instead of using subprocesses at all.

For example, in Python 3.5 with [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), you can get all the directories in the working directory extremely efficiently with:

```
import os

dirs = [x.name for x in os.scandir() if x.is_dir()]
```

On earlier versions of Python, `os.listdir` + `os.path.isdir` can be used to do the same thing slightly less efficiently (it involves a `stat` of each entry which `os.scandir` can avoid, but for small directories and/or local filesystems, the `stat` cost is trivial):

```
import os, os.path

dirs = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(f)]
```

Comment: You might want to include the explicit `os.Popen('ls -ld */', shell=True)` call in your answer to moot the need the OP felt to edit that into their question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `os.Popen` isn't a thing (assume you meant `subprocess.Popen`). And I'm extremely reluctant to provide code examples using `shell=True`; it's not hard to figure out how to do it from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html); people who won't read the docs for something this simple are the same sorts of people who would ignore all the text saying "`shell=True` is a _terrible_ idea" and just blindly copy-paste the terrible code. Particularly in this case, where using subprocesses at all is a terrible idea; Python built-ins will be faster, easier, more secure.

Comment: I do agree with you on that case; using builtins is also more correct -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I added example code for getting a list of directories from the working directory the right way; you're right that I should provide the good example code to counteract the relentless drive to write bad code. :-)

Comment: Doesn't `is_dir()` do a stat call anyhow? I'm not sure it's avoidable here. (Granted, two is more than one, but if it's basically guaranteed to be in the cache...)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Nope, that's the brilliance of `os.scandir`; on UNIX-like systems, it's exposing the `opendir`/`readdir` API; [`readdir` gets you `d_type` for free as part of iteration](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), it only `stat`s if the entry is a symlink (and you can prevent that by passing `follow_symlinks=False` to `is_dir()`); if it does need to `stat`, it caches it so additional tests don't `stat` again. On Windows, using `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`, it almost never `stat`s for any metadata, because that API gives all the info for free with a single read from the file system.